# What is the meaning of ++(*p)?

Tags: operator-keyword, postfix-mta

According to a KNK Modern Approach Textbook, The expression of ++(*p) is that “ Increment *p first; value of expression is *p after increment”.

When I first interpreted this, I thought it would first fetch a value of *p to which pointer points, and then increment the value. So its result is 11 if *p is 10.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, if `p` points to int with value 10, then ++(*p) will increment this value to 11 and return 11 as a result.

Comment: I got it. It was same meaning.  Thank you